# why I'am getting this error? message: Could not read pom.xml, in the first line of the code

Tags: maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>temp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Temp</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

like so

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not read pom.xml    at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readModel(MavenImpl.java:565)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readModel(MavenImpl.java:574)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:542)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:498)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused
>   by: org.apache.maven.model.io.ModelParseException: Duplicated tag:
>   'build' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n\n\t...
>   @65:9)    at
>   org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readModel(MavenImpl.java:563)
>     ... 24 more Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: Duplicated
>   tag: 'build' (position: START_TAG seen
>   ...\n\n\t... @65:9)     at
>   org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.checkFieldWithDuplicate(MavenXpp3Reader.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parseModel(MavenXpp3Reader.java:2275)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3845)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:117)
>     ... 26 more

Comment: The error says you have duplicate `<build>` tag but the code posted do no have duplicate. Are you sure that you are running form the correct folder?

Comment: @yogesh  [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>] in this line I'am getting error with red cross mark, i have closed project tag at the end

Comment: yes, I'am pretty sure @KarthikeyanVaithilingam

Comment: If you are on macOS or linux use `cat pom.xml` from the terminal and in on windows use `type pom.xml` from command prompt and check the pom.xml is the same as you posted

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified". has popped in command prompt

Comment: The you are not in the correct folder

Comment: what should I do now !?

Comment: sorry that's not the error message, but in markers log there is 1 problem (maven configuration problem). which describes "unknown"

Answer (score 0):

The message says there's a duplicate `<build>` tag in your `pom.xml` at line 65:

`Duplicated tag: 'build' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n\n\t... @65:9)`

However, the `pom.xml` you posted is totally fine. Maybe you have another `pom.xml` in your project somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The pom file has an error in it.  In my case, an opening tag did not match the closing tag.

I found the exact problem by creating a new java project and then copying the pom  file to there.  When I tried to open the pom file, Eclipse gave a message stating the exact error that was preventing the pom file from being read.

Answer (score 0):

Check the maven version you are using in my case I was using 3.9.0 and I downgrade to 3.8.6 as for the project I was trying to run "mvn clean install" have configure 3.8.6 version.